# SMTP fails with Status: 5.3.5 when sending to a local mail server

Tags: domain-name-system, email, iis, smtp

In our network, we have na IBM Lotus Notes server, which handles emails for basedomain.com.

Recently we introduced a new IIS Smtp server just for sending automated emails. The Smtp is configured for a domain  subdomain.basedomain.com.
The server also has a DNS record for subdomain.basedomain.com

Sending emails outside of our network works fine, however it fails when we try to send an email to recipient@basedomain.com  - the email returns with an 5.3.5 error.

We even tried the SMTPDiag tool to test the connection and it ended OK, it listed the correct end-server for email address recipient@basedomain.com.

Why doesnt it work when sending real email?

Comment: could you post the actual error message?

Comment: The message just says 5.3.5

Answer (score 0):

5.3.5 is a loopback error, meanining it cannot relay to itself.

It seems your new SMTP is trying to do just that when handling @basedomain mail.

Could be helpfull to see the IIS config

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).